# Repeat every element in a 2D array to a 2D output

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D array like this one -

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([(1,2),(4,6)])
```

I want this output -

```
arr2 = array([1,1,2,2], [4,4,6,6])
```

What I have so far is giving me 1D output:

```
arr2=[]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    a = arr[i,:]
    for j in range(len(a)):
        arr2.append(a[j])
        arr2.append(a[j])

np.array(arr2)
array([1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6])
```

any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```py
arr = np.repeat(arr, 2).reshape((2, -1))
print(arr)
```

Prints:

```
[[1 1 2 2]
 [4 4 6 6]]
```